# Kubernetes ingress wildcard no longer working

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

After updating onprem kubernetes from 1.18 to 1.22.5, I had to switch the ingress api versions from `v1beta1` to `v1`, and selected `ImplementationSpecific` as the new, required `pathType`.

```
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: wx-ing-example
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "*.example.com"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: wx-example
                port:
                  number: 80
```

Since the update, subdomains beyond one level aren't being sent to the service, and instead return a 404. I.e. bar.example.com is working, but foo.bar.example.com is not.

I've tried changing `pathType` to `Prefix` with no change in behaviour.

`k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v1.1.0`

Answer (score 2):

What you are descibing is expected behavior according to the [official kubernetes ingress documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#hostname-wildcards).

| Host | Host header | Match? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| *.foo.com | bar.foo.com | Matches based on shared suffix |
| *.foo.com | baz.bar.foo.com | No match, wildcard only covers a single DNS label |
| *.foo.com | foo.com | No match, wildcard only covers a single DNS label |

`PathType` has nothing to do with that. This is about the host header.

The only option I know of, is leaving the host completely away. So it will match any request that is able to find its way to your ingress controller. Depending on your situation, this may not be desirable.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: any-host
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: sample
            port:
              number: 80
```

Comment: Yeah, I came across that documentation as well. I guess I'm just confused about why it was working fine before. I'm having trouble finding any deprecation or changelog that might affect it.  

I likely can't remove the host completely. I have over a hundred of these ingresses pointing at a corresponding service and deployment. One per open ticket in our bug tracking system.

Comment: Yes, in most cases using a single entrypoint ingress isn't feasible. Apart from that, I think  in most cases it's doable to go down to 1 level wildcard.  In the worst case you need to specify multiple ingress resources with different level of wildcards to cover more cases.